# Changing the column size in postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I currently have a table in postgresql named `companies`.
`companies` has a column `name` whose length is `30`, but now I want to reduce the length of column upto `20` characters, but unfortunately I have some entries in that column of upto length 25-30. Can anyone suggest me how can I reduce the size of column without losing any data entry?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
alter table companies alter COLUMN name type varchar(20);
```

but I get this:

> ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(20)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The natural way is to truncate names longer than 20 characters:

```sql
update companies
set name = substr(name, 1, 20)
where length(name) > 20;

alter table companies 
    alter column name type varchar(20);
```

However, you can do the same with a single command, which should be significantly faster:

```sql
alter table companies 
    alter column name type varchar(20) 
    using name::varchar(20);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't reduce the size of the column without shortening the existing records.

If all you want is to prevent new records being created where the length is more than 20 this can be achieved with a trigger that validates the length and rejects the record if its too long.

[Create Trigger](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html)